# DismissAction for Preview

Tags: swiftui, preview, dismiss

I am trying to solve an issue with DismissAction in Preview.
This is in the View: let parentDismiss: DismissAction

This is what I have in Preview:

```
struct MilkingView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MilkingView(parentDismiss: DismissAction())
    }
}
```

But I constantly have an error **'DismissAction' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers**

DismissAction() doesn't help as well as DismissAction.

Comment: You need to define the `func DismissAction` in `MilkingView_Previews` in order to use it. That is what the error is telling you. Further, you wouldn't call the function, ie. use the "()" when passing it in to a view. You would simply pass it. If you want more than that, you need to create a a [Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Yrb I was trying to add DismissAction because I had an error "Missing argument for parameter 'parentDismiss' in call"

Comment: Yes, you must supply it, but you can't make it up out of thin air. `DismissAction` does not exist in the preview provider. You have to code it in the preview provider. If you don't actually need to do anything when the func is called, but just need it to compile, you can pass an empty closure `{}`

Comment: @Yrb thanks. Could answer me in details and I will accepte this as the best answer?

Comment: I missed this comment earlier. What questions do you have specifically regarding my answer?

Answer (score 1):

This should be enough to make the preview build, if you simply need to provide a function, but don't need it to actually do anything:

```
struct MilkingView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MilkingView(parentDismiss: {})
    }
}
```

if you do, you can always do something like:

```
struct MilkingView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MilkingView(parentDismiss: {
            print("Doing something...")
        })
    }
}
```

There is no need to do more than this. It is a preview provider showing just part of the UI.

Comment: Thank you very much but it doesn't work. I have an error **Cannot convert value of type '() -> ()' to expected argument type 'DismissAction'**

Comment: Please post the code for `DismissAction`. Also, what scope is it declared in?

Comment: DismissAction is not my code, but Apple's -- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/DismissAction

Comment: Please post the other part of the code. If Preview is making you supply `dismiss`, you are using it incorrectly.

Comment: omg guys, it's not hard. There's a struct, ok? It has this:
`private var dismissParent: DismissAction`
Then an init like this:
`init(_ something, dismissParent: DismissAction)`
Now, how do we trick the preview?
We can't declare a new "DismissAction" type because it behaves as a function.

Answer (score 1):

For other's who come across this. Define your dismiss action in the struct as a static property.

```
@Environment(\.dismiss) static private var dismiss
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to solve your problem the right way, but I am using a workaround, and it works for me.

So, bear with me.

I have a `.sheet` that has a view inside. That view has a list of `NavigationLink` items, and they will open a form in a third view. From that form I should be able to close the sheet.

So..

`Main view > List (in a sheet) > Form (close from here)`

So on my list view I have this:

```
@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
// (...)
NavigationLink {
    MyForm(something, dismissParent: dismiss)
} label: {
    Text(title)
}
```

On my form view, that lives inside that list, I pass my dismiss into the initialiser. The init originally looked like this:

```
private var dismissParent: DismissAction

init(_ something, dismissParent: DismissAction) {
    self.something = something
    self.dismissParent = dismissParent
}
```

Of course, that breaks the preview, as your own code. What I did was pass a closure as a callback. So I modified my code, like so:

```
private var dismissParent: () -> Void

init(_ something, dismissParent: @escaping () -> Void) {
    self.something = something
    self.dismissParent = dismissParent
}
```

On the parent I got this:

```
@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
// (...)
NavigationLink {
    MyForm(something) {
        dismiss()
    }
} label: {
    Text(title)
}
```

And on the preview I do:

```
#if DEBUG
struct MyForm_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ZStack {
            MyForm(
                dummySomething,
                dismissParent: {}
            )
        }
    }
}
#endif
```

I use that `ZStack` there because preview for some reason seems to break a lot when I'm dealing with views in sheets. I don't know why, but this fixes it.

I also use annotation `#if DEBUG` and `#endif` because I realised that the preview code is compiled in some situations and it bloats the app needlessly. I use that to exclude preview from the final code. (I don't know if that was fixed or not, I don't have time or patience to pursue this kind of information, but it doesn't break my code, so I'm happy.)

It works for me. Try that.